DAX Formula For Unpivot
I'm attempting to create a dax query to count the number of fields passed, fields failed and total fields from an unpivoted table.
A Quality Check has been done on certain fields and things are marked as pass, fail or untested. I've created a dummy of what it looks like, but the real thing has more fields and is pushing about 10,000 rows.
The logic is that a name is entered, X amount of fields are tested and passed/failed and then the total populates at the side. When i've moved the data from excel over to power bi, i unpivoted the data so that it was easier to decipher a count of pass/failed fields (i.e it would save me doing 3 formulas for premium - one count for pass, one for fail, one for untest). However, as it's now been unpivoted, the fields tested have duplicated so rather than a few thousand rows, it's counting 1m + .
I don't have the expertise in Power BI/DAX to decipher the easiest way to do this.
PRIOR TO PIVOT EXAMPLE:
Reference | Premium | Inception | Claims | QA Comments | Fields Tested | Pass          | Fail
ABC       | Pass    | Pass      | Fail   |             | 3             | 2             | 1
CDE       | Fail    | Pass      | Pass   | Notes       | 3             | 2             | 1
FGH       | Pass    | Untested  | Pass   |             | 2             | 2             | 0

POST PIVOT EXAMPLE:

Reference | Attribute        | Value | Fields Tested | Fields Passed | Fields Failed
ABC       | Premium          | Pass  | 3             | 2             | 1
ABC       | Inception        | Pass  | 3             | 2             | 1
ABC       | Claims           | Fail  | 3             | 2             | 1
CDE       | Premium          | Fail  | 3             | 2             | 1
CDE       | Inception        | Pass  | 3             | 2             | 1
CDE       | Claims           | Pass  | 3             | 2             | 1
FGH       | Premium          | Pass  | 2             | 2             | 0
FGH       | Inception        | Untested | 2         | 2             | 0
FGH       | Claims           | Pass  | 2             | 2             | 0


I want to see an accurate total for each field. i.e ABC = 3 Fields Tested/FGH = 2 Fields Tested rather than at the moment ABC for example would have a fields tested of 9 (3+3+3).
I've tried to COUNTDISTINCT my references but after that I get a little confused of where to go next.

Create a calculated table where you combines multiple the tables together using UNION, and SELECTCOLUMNS to selects the columns you need and renames them as required.
UnpivotedTable = 
UNION(
    SELECTCOLUMNS(
        MyData, 
        "Reference", MyData[Reference], 
        "Attribute", "Premium", 
        "Value", MyData[Premium], 
        "Fields Tested", MyData[Fields Tested],
        "Fields Passed", MyData[Pass], 
        "Fields Failed", MyData[Fail]
    ),
    SELECTCOLUMNS(
        MyData, 
        "Reference", MyData[Reference], 
        "Attribute", "Inception", 
        "Value", MyData[Inception], 
        "Fields Tested", MyData[Fields Tested],
        "Fields Passed", MyData[Pass], 
        "Fields Failed", MyData[Fail]
    ),
    SELECTCOLUMNS(
        MyData, 
        "Reference", MyData[Reference], 
        "Attribute", "Claims", 
        "Value", MyData[Claims], 
        "Fields Tested", MyData[Fields Tested],
        "Fields Passed", MyData[Pass], 
        "Fields Failed", MyData[Fail]
    )
)



Thanks for this, really appreciate you taking the time to help out. Following on from doing UNION + SELECT COLUMNS, what is the next step to select the fields tested (in the example's case i'd want the total output to be 8 (3+3+2).
